# Is it all right for my design to remind another design?

Tags: web-app

I've made a web design but the layout of the design is already employed on another popular web app, and practically only on that web app, that looking at it immediately reminds you of it. Is this acceptable, or should it be avoided?

Answer (score 3):

One of the first pieces of research that designers do when thinking about design solutions is competitor analysis, which is just a fancy way of saying "checking out other designs for the same user problem". There is not always a need to reinvent the wheel, and it is even helpful to keep certain user flows or patterns consistent throughout the web as users often expect websites/apps to behave in ways that they are familiar with.

Having said that, your web app and its users will have specific problems that you are trying to solve so you should design for those. It's hard to say where to draw the line between completely copying something and taking inspiration from it. Make sure you are designing for your individual web app and its users first. You can take inspiration from other apps but if everyone's reaction when they come to yours is 'oh this is X app but with a different logo at the top', it is unlikely that you have succeeded in creating an app just for your users.